# Modifying Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Am trying to modify my bootstrap navbar to display some links(list item) on different media screen, for example on my navbar list I have some list including search and login/signup list items, so on phone or tablet I want to display search and login/signup list items and my navbar-brand, instead of showing only the navbar-brand and collapsing all the lists item, have tried different methods e.g excluding my search and login/signup list items from the dropdown list etc. but still not working.

Here is my HTML code but the CSS is just bootstrap css(bootstrap.css).
And please help me, if you can do that without bootstrap as well. [View the working code on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mudonodoba/1/edit).

Or

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class = "navbar-header">
        <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#mynav">
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand">Stack Ask</a>
    </div>

    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "mynav">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
            <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Education</a></li>
            <li class = "dropdown"><a class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown" href = "#">Tutorials
                <span class = "caret"></span>
                </a>
                <div class = "dropdown-menu">
                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href = "#">Programming Languages</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Web Development</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href = "#">Kingdom Centre</a></li>
            <li><a href = "">About</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class = "dropdown"><a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</a>

                <div class = "dropdown-menu">
                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <form class="form-search">
                                <div class = "container-fluid">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-medium search-query" style = "border-radius: 25px;" />
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn" style = "margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 5px;">Search</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></span> Log In</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: check now http://jsbin.com/xiyajafuhu/2/  you can use `hidden-xs` class to hide any element in extra small screen and similarly visible-xs for showing any element in extra small screen.

Comment: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/f43a85bb94c927a67e3e019eca645d9b579e6554/68747470733a2f2f662e636c6f75642e6769746875622e636f6d2f6173736574732f3136383338332f3936333833392f34386234383634322d303530612d313165332d386638632d3866343062383866623435322e706e67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well alternatively you can make use of `hidden-xs`, `hidden-sm`, `hidden-md` and `hidden-lg` class to show and hide particular `ul`'s, perhaps you need to make copy of your `ul`!!  Your updated code would be as below:
**[Bin here](http://jsbin.com/zidegeyida/1/edit?html,css,output)**

```css
.mob-nav>li
{
  float:left
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class = "navbar-header">
              <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#mynav">
           <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand">Stack Ask</a>
                  <ul class = "mob-nav hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg nav navbar-nav ">
           <li class = "dropdown"><a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</a>
                <div class = "dropdown-menu">
                 <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
               <li>
                   <form class="form-search">
                        <div class = "container-fluid">
                             <input type="text" class="form-control input-medium search-query" style = "border-radius: 25px;" />
                             <button type="submit" class="btn" style = "margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 5px;">Search</button>
                        </div>
                       </form>
                 </li>
            </ul>
           </div>
           </li>
           <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
         <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></span> Log In</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "mynav">
           <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
         <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href = "#">Education</a></li>
         <li class = "dropdown">
                            <a class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown" href = "#">Tutorials
           <span class = "caret"></span>
          </a>
          <div class = "dropdown-menu">
           <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href = "#">Programming Languages</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Web Development</a></li>
           </ul>
          </div>
         </li>
         <li><a href = "#">Kingdom Centre</a></li>
         <li><a href = "">About</a></li>
         </ul>
          
         <ul class = "hidden-xs nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li class = "dropdown"><a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</a>
           
         <div class = "dropdown-menu">
         <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
             <li>
                <form class="form-search">
                     <div class = "container-fluid">
                             <input type="text" class="form-control input-medium search-query" style = "border-radius: 25px;" />
                          <button type="submit" class="btn" style = "margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 5px;">Search</button>
                  </div>
                    </form>
              </li>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </li>
           
       <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
       <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></span> Log In</a></li>
          </ul>
     </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but do you know how to achieve this without using bootstrap.

Comment: use media queries as suggested by @KarthiKeyan

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want collapse property for the search, login, etc... so that please tack out the second ul outside the collapse div and add unique class to select via media quires (ex: info) and add below code

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .info li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: This also works as well, but do you know how to achieve this without using bootstrap.

Comment: Just remove the collapse navbar-collapse div and add custom JS toggle for mobile menu